# How do I delete/remove a broken configuration?

Tags: 8, layout-builder

I'm using Layout Builder to manage the display of a content type.
I was playing around with the config and adding different things, and something I added caused the page to crash and now I get this error:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityMalformedException: The "node" entity cannot have a URI as it does not have an ID in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityBase->toUrl() (line 191 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityBase.php). node_tokens('node', Array, Array, Array, Object)

This error persists every time I click "Manage Display" for that content type; I rebuilt the cache with Drush and cleared my browser cache, but I still get the error when I go to edit the display settings.  I get the error when I log in with a different browser, too, and also when I revert the config.

I am working on this site locally, so I can pull from the dev server, but is there another way to reset my "unsaved changes" locally so that I don't have to wait for the pull to complete?

Comment: Can you get a full error message with backtrace to see which code is trying to get a URI from a node without ID?

Comment: It's DB related, you don't need to pull the code base, just import the dev db again assuming you haven't made any config changes that you want to push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layout builder stores in-progress modifications to the layout config in the `key_value_expire` table. Whenever Layout Builder is loaded (e.g. Manage Display, Page Manager, etc.), it first checks that table if there is an in-progress entry for the layout you're about to edit. If it exists, it tries to load that, otherwise it loads the one saved in config.

The problem is, that in-progress config may contain bad data (e.g. a block that was added but has bad implementation) or outdated data (e.g. a block that you were working on, but whose implementation has already been deleted). This can cause Layout Builder to fail loading. As far as I know, Drupal has no way of guarding or recovering from this from the admin side nor does a cache rebuild help.

One way to recover is to load a copy of the DB prior to your changes, but that may take forever and blow away any other work in progress you have. Another is to dive into the `key_value_expire` table and look for that in-progress entry, delete it, and reload Layout Builder.