# How to reset a field formatter settings or layout builder configuration

Tags: layout-builder

I was settings up an images field through layout builder. Change it from `Bootstrap Basic Image Gallery` to `OwlCarousel`.

When I submit the form, the UI does not have any response. and then I refresh the page, the website crash on this configuration page. `/admin/commerce/config/product-types/easel/edit/display/default/layout`

I wonder if there is any method to reset field formatter settings or the layout builder configuration.

PAGE ERROR:

```
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\MissingValueContextException: Required contexts without a value: entity in Drupal\Core\Plugin\Context\ContextHandler->applyContextMapping() (line 155 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Plugin/Context/ContextHandler.php).
Drupal\layout_builder\SectionComponent->getPlugin(Array) (Line: 70)
Drupal\layout_builder\Event\SectionComponentBuildRenderArrayEvent->__construct(Object, Array, 1) (Line: 89)
Drupal\layout_builder\SectionComponent->toRenderArray(Array, 1) (Line: 87)
Drupal\layout_builder\Section->toRenderArray(Array, 1) (Line: 240)
Drupal\layout_builder\Element\LayoutBuilder->buildAdministrativeSection(Object, 1) (Line: 124)
Drupal\layout_builder\Element\LayoutBuilder->layout(Object) (Line: 98)
Drupal\layout_builder\Element\LayoutBuilder->preRender(Array)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 101)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doTrustedCallback(Array, Array, 'Render #pre_render callbacks must be methods of a class that implements \Drupal\Core\Security\TrustedCallbackInterface or be an anonymous function. The callback was %s. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2966725', 'exception', 'Drupal\Core\Render\Element\RenderCallbackInterface') (Line: 772)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doCallback('#pre_render', Array, Array) (Line: 363)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array) (Line: 435)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 201)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, ) (Line: 241)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}() (Line: 564)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 242)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 132)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, 'kernel.view', Object)
call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.view', Object) (Line: 142)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch(Object, 'kernel.view') (Line: 174)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 81)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 58)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 709)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Answer (score 2):

REF: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/310906/109110

I got the layout-builder back after deleting `name = 'commerce_product.easel.default'` from table `key_value_expire`